# Do math across two arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, math, duplicates, subtraction

I need to subtract one array from another, by index: 
a = [3,4,3,5]
b = [1,2,2,1]

c = [2,2,1,4]

Comment: `c = a.map.with_index {|e,i| e - b[i]}`

Comment: ...or `a.each_index.map { |i| a[i]-b[i] }` or `a.zip(b).map { |x,y| x-y }`.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`Array#zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-zip) and then [`Array#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
 a = [3,4,3,5]
 b = [1,2,2,1]

 c = a.zip(b).map { |a, b| a - b }
 #=> [2, 2, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do it in Ruby. Some examples:

1. The most straightforward approach:

```
a = [3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 5.0]

b = [1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0]

length = 4

c = Array.new(length, 0.0) # Where 0.0 is default array value.

length.times do |i|
  c[i] = a[i] - b[i]
end
```

2. Using [`Vector`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html) class from Ruby standard library:

```
require 'matrix'

a = Vector[3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 5.0]

b = Vector[1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0]

(a - b).to_a
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you again for helping me to make my answer better.

Comment: That is my advice. It’s common for SO members to not know when to stop when writing answers. Many an excellent answer has been made worse by the addition of peripheral bumf, imo. Note you have `vector_c.to_a`, but `c = b - a`. `(a-b).to_a #=> [2, 2, 1, 4]` would commonly be written here to show the result of the calculation. Also, nothing is added by assignIng the result to a variable.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Done. I have removed 'dynamic build' from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Enumerable#inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject).

```
a = [3, 4, 3, 5]
b = [1, 2, 2, 1]

с = a.zip(b).map { |i| i.inject(&:-) }
# => [2, 2, 1, 4]
```

I like `:-)` symbols there :-)